# How to apply animation on the list items such that during an instance of time only one list item is visible?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Rotation.css">
        <div class="text_rotate">
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hi there are three list items in above code I want to produce an effect that will show only one element at an instant of time for example One should be displayed initially then it gets **hidden** then **two shows** up and so on and once the list is ended the first element shows up i.e. loop for infinite.

This can be achieved through keyframes but I don't know how since I am new to CSS, any guidance in this direction is welcomed please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized its for sure doable only with CSS, here is your code

https://jsfiddle.net/u6mno29m/1/

HTML

```
 <div class="text_rotate">
    <ul>
      <li class="rotate">One</li>
      <li class="rotate">Two</li>
      <li class="rotate">Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.rotate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

.rotate:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 30s 0s infinite linear;
          animation: rotate 30s 0s infinite linear;
}

.rotate:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 30s 10s infinite linear;
          animation: rotate 30s 10s infinite linear;
}

.rotate:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 30s 20s infinite linear;
          animation: rotate 30s 20s infinite linear;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes "rotate" {
 0% {
   opacity: 0;
 }
 2% {
   opacity: 1;
 }
 31% {
   opacity: 1;
 }
 33% {
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity: 0;
 }
}

 @keyframes "rotate" {
 0% {
   opacity: 0;
 }
 2% {
   opacity: 1;
 }
 31% {
   opacity: 1;
 }
 33% {
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity: 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Karle coincidentally I just got the solution by trying the same method some hours before, Nevertheless thank you for efforts and for the jQuery approach

Answer (score 1):

To loop it you would have to use js, with CSS animations you could just let them appear and disappear after a specific time

Update, u can loop it with CSS as well see other answer!

https://jsfiddle.net/56aoup2q/

HTML

```
<div class="text_rotate">
<ul class="loop">
    <li class="show" >One</li>
    <li class="show" >Two</li>
    <li class="show">Three</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.show {
  display:none;
}
```

JS (jquery):

```
 var $elem = $('#loop .show'), e = $elem.length, i = 0;

function loop() {
    $elem.eq(i % e).fadeIn(500, function() {
        $elem.eq(i % e).fadeOut(500, loop);
        i++;
    });
}

loop();
```